# How to capture all the test result from pytest-repeat

Tags: python, pytest

I am trying to do some KPI tests. And I want to re-test it 10 times and then calculate the average.
But I don't know how to capture each test result.

Here is my code.

```
@pytest.mark.repeat(2)
def test_hdmi(request):
    # logging.info(request.__dict__)
    # logging.info('-'*50)
    # logging.info(request.node.__dict__)
    # logging.info('-' * 50)
    # logging.info(request.instance)
    # logging.info('-' * 50)
    # logging.info(request.module.__dict__)
    # logging.info('-' * 50)
    rdk_ir.send('input')
    kpi = pytest.gpio.count_kpi(0, rdk_lux.get_note('pure_white_50_40')[test_inch])
    logging.info(f'kpi {kpi} secnods')
    time.sleep(1)
```

Kpi is the test result I want. Can anyone who can help me?

Comment: Isn't better to change the test itself to retrieve N kpis and take the average?

Comment: Yeah, it is easy to change the test . But I got more than 100 test cases. If I can invoke a hook or something. It will be more easy to finish the test suite.

Comment: Then maybe you need to have a method, average-kpis(repeat=n, time-to-sleep-in-between=1), in your codebase

Comment: Okay, thanks for your advice